# Calculate the power with multithreads

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, math

I'm working on a calculator which only calculates a number to the power of another number. This happens with this code:

```
public BigInteger generate(long Power, long Base){

    BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(Base), 
    a = BigInteger.valueOf(Base);
    int j=0;

    while(j!=Power-1){
        result = result.multiply(a);
        j++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I would like to know if there is any mathematical way to split this type of calculation to multiple threads, so that my program will calculate things like 987654321 ^ 987654321 much faster. My CPU does have 6 cores so if there is a way to use them all at once for this stuff it would be great.

Comment: Without threads: You should start with transforming a^b into (a^(b div 2))^2 * a^(b mod 2) if b is big enough.

Comment: I'd start using a better algorithm for single thread exponentiation, like [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is factorization, i.e., write the base number as a product

```
Base = a_1 * ... * a_n
```

and then compute `a_i^b` on separate threads, and multiply the results. You need some computational effort for finding a factorization, but I would first check if numbers are ´big enough´ to bother with multiple cores, and if they are, start with some standard checks if factorization is possible. Or just divide by the first 100 prime numbers, that should not take long.

Especially, if the number factorizes *several times* by the same factor, you just have to compute the power once, i.e.,

```
(24)^5 = (3*2*2*2)^5 = 3^5 * 2^5 * 2^5 * 2^5
```

and so you compute `r_1 = 3^5` and `r_2 = 2^5` and then multiply the result is `r = r_1 * r_2 * r_2 * r_2`.

You can also factorize the exponents, but then the algorithm will be a tad more complicated.

Comment: *The first thing that comes to mind is factorization* Well, perhaps not if you want to speed up your calculations, factorization is a known hard problem.  I'd like to see some experimental data to convince me that factorization, as a preliminary step, would actually lead to a faster parallel algorithm.  In the absence of experimental data, an argument from first principles, based on the computational complexities of the operations involved would be satisfactory.

Comment: Because turning a problem in P (exponentiation) into a problem in BQP (integer factorization) is sure the best way to speed things up. And this was sarcasm.

Comment: Sure, finding the prime factorization is hard and much more computation-intense. But finding a factorization can be pretty fast (like I mentioned, by guessing and probing), and since that may cut the time of the whole computation in half or less (depending on the number of factors and cores/threads), I still think the time gained in average is big.

Comment: I did not claim that this is an algorithm that solves teh problem in less time, I proposed how one could easily utilize multithreads. Ofc there will be times when the probing algorithm doesn't find factors. In those cases, well, we dont multithread. That's why the probing part should be 'small' compared to the expected time for the full computation

Comment: No, integer factorization, prime or not is in BQP and no polynomial time algorithm is known.